# Is it possible to share a DXVA surface?

Tags: directx, direct3d, dxva

I'm using DXVA video decoder. It works fine, but I want to share the decompressed surfaces with another IDirect3D9 device object.

I read [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb219800%28v=vs.85%29.aspx#Sharing_Resources) document, and I'm calling **[IDirectXVideoDecoderService::CreateSurface()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms696227%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)** method to create surfaces, and I try to pass a non-NULL **HANDLE*** which points to NULL as the last parameter for the method. But the method fails with 0x8876086c (**D3DERR_INVALIDCALL**) result. I also tried to allocate an array of HANDLEs and set every element to NULL, then pass this array as a parameter, but still getting the same error.

Is there a way to share DXVA surfaces between IDirect3D9 devices?

Comment: *"...pass a non-NULL HANDLE* which points to NULL..."* - Can you show the section of code? As I read it, I'm not clear exactly what you're passing.

Answer (score 1):

Reading the document :

> Resource creation APIs include - CreateTexture, CreateVolumeTexture, CreateCubeTexture, CreateRenderTarget, CreateVertexBuffer, CreateIndexBuffer, CreateDepthStencilSurface, CreateOffscreenPlainSurface, CreateDepthStencilSurfaceEx, CreateOffscreenPlainSurfaceEx, and CreateRenderTargetEx.

IDirectXVideoAccelerationService::CreateSurface seems not to be included.

And :

> pSharedHandle [in, out]
>
> A pointer to a handle that is used to share the surfaces between Direct3D devices. Set this parameter to NULL.

It seems not to be possible to use it.